# CSS word wrapping causes huge spaces between words

Tags: html, css, whitespace, word-wrap

[image: Huge space between words when wrapped]

Hi! When the window is resized, the text automatically wraps to fit its container nicely. For this, I'm using this CSS code:

```
article {
    overflow: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Though it seems, that this has no effect at all. When I remove this piece of code, the behavior doesn't change: the text is still wrapped near the end of the line.

I'm complaining about the huge gaps between words. I've observed a few webpages where no extra code is used for this and it still works nicely. Can you please help me get rid of the space? Thank you!

Comment: Do you happen to have `text-align: justify` defined somewhere else?

Comment: What is your line-height set to?

Comment: looks like text-align:justify is triggered , from a parent maybe ? , anyhow, you can reset it to text-align:left. word-wrap:break-word; only break word if it doesn't stand on one single line

Comment: You've got to be picking up a `text-align:justify` from somewhere; `break-word` doesn't do that. http://jsfiddle.net/H47E4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that the `text-align: justify` has been inherited from the parent html tags.
You could also try modifying the CSS as follows:

```
article {
    overflow: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: start;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments `article` seems to be inheriting `text-align: justify;`. Here's a way to fix the alignment:

http://jsfiddle.net/awesome/zs394/2/

```
article, .unjust {
    /* regular */
    text-align: left;

    /* super strength */
    text-align: left !important;
}
```